# Postgresql :Syntax issue in MERGE with JSON param in stored function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Facing syntax issue when I have json input, which needs to be insert/update values from JSON into the table which is a **view**

**Expected**

1. When Primary id matched with Item_id (**PK**) - update its corresponding values
2. When Primary id not matched with Item_id (**PK**) - insert into the view

**Sample SP**

```
drop function if exists sp_post_itemsx;
CREATE FUNCTION sp_post_itemsx(i_data jsonb)
RETURNS VOID
AS $function$
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO vw_item_status_detail 
    USING  
    (SELECT 
      i_data->>'fulfillerId' fulfillerId, 
      t->>'itemId' itemId, 
      i_data->>'orderId' orderId, 
      1000,
      t->>'skuCode' skuCode,
      t->>'decorationTechnology' decorationTechnology,
      (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity ,
      NOW()
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items')) as t ON item_id = t.itemId

 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
        vw.quantity = t.quantity

 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT INTO vw_item_status_detail(
      fulfiller_id,
      item_id,
      order_id,
      status_id,
      sku_code,
      decoration_technology,
      quantity,
      item_updated_time)
   SELECT 
      i_data->>'fulfillerId' fulfillerId, 
      t->>'itemId' itemId, 
      i_data->>'orderId' orderId, 
      1000,
      t->>'skuCode' skuCode,
      t->>'decorationTechnology' decorationTechnology,
      (t->>'quantity')::numeric quantity ,
      NOW()
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(i_data  -> 'items') t ;
  
END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ERROR: "vw_item_status_detail" is not a known variable

Not sure what is wrong with the syntax or MERGE doesn't work with insert for views table

Comment: There is no `MERGE` statement in Postgres

Comment: [Found this link for reference](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) found this and many other url for reference. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Is there any other optimal and easy way to achieve similar task if MERGE is not an option ? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Well, the current [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) should be your reference for currently supported statements, not some discussion on the mailing list if or how such a thing is implemented. The alternative is an `insert ... on conflict () do update`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+upsert